# white board at the end of the site

Tags: html, css

I have a white board at the end of the site, but only at the end of the 1 page on 4. I try whit add `heigh:100vh` nothing change, when i utlizie the analizer on firefox, no paading or margin on the footer or on the section.

[image]

```css
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-padding-top: 9rem;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    height: 100vh;
 }
    
body {
    background:var(--bg);
 }
```

```html
<section class="footer">

  <div class="share">

      <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fab fa-pinterest"></a>

  </div>

  <div class="links">

      <a href="Home.html">Home</a>
      <a href="Home.html#about">About</a>
      <a href="Ricette.html">Ricette</a>
      <a href="Foto.html">Foto</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

  </div>

<div class="credit">created by <span>Nicolo' Caporali</span> </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Try to read about reset or normalize css

Comment: my question is what is it that makes that makes the white on the bottom of the page. And why only in 1 page

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this before all your code

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: nop, don't works.  I try to add anothec section whit a random content. In this case whe white board don't show

Comment: Let's see, could you please add correct snippets in your example

Comment: i can't add cuz is to much code D;

Comment: Try to inspect page and find an element that cause this strange behavior, then after you find it go through  its styles. I'm sure you will find what's going on!

Comment: i already try nothing wrong whit it